# Aggregate ranking from multiple ranked lists

Tags: ranking

I have multiples lists which are ordered. How do I generate a final list with all elements in all lists ranked by their cumulative rank? I.e. the `Final` column here:

[image: Global ranking of multiple ranked lists]

I can't obtain the data with the fruits as a column and other columns with the fruit's numeric ranks. I.e., I can't do:

$\begin{array}{c|cc}
Fruits&Alice&Bob&...\\
\hline
Apple&1&1&...\\
Orange&2&0&...\\
...&...&...&...
\end{array}$

Comment: Not sure to understand why you can't. Is that a question on how to do a pivot table in excel ? The problem of creating a rank is interesting though, have a look at Voting theory and Arrow's impossibility theorem

Comment: @Scratch I meant I won't be able to obtain the data like in the second table. I don't have any experience using pivot table, can you point me to an example which will have similar results like in the first table?

Thanks for Arrow's impossibility theorem. I came across it earlier, but wasn't sure it would help.. I'll check it out

Answer (score 3):

This is not so much a problem of statistics as it is a problem in what is called [social choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_choice_theory). A short introduction to some of the basic results can be found [here](http://www.econ2.uni-bonn.de/teaching/summerterm-2011-1/downloads/slidespart-3.pdf).

In general, there does not exist one "optimal" ranking. You have to specify what exactly you want your ranking to satisfy for you to be able to choose one optimally.